# Cent0S 7 and Mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I can not start mariadb/mysql the innodb file became corrupt after hard shut down. Now after working on it I get this. I replace the entire `/var/lib/mysql` direct with a backup copy and after that I get this.

```
Apr 29 23:43:38 host systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Apr 29 23:43:47 host systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Apr 29 23:43:47 host systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed to run 'start-pre' task: Structure needs cleaning
Apr 29 23:43:47 host systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Apr 29 23:46:33 host systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Apr 29 23:46:33 host systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed to run 'start-pre' task: Structure needs cleaning
Apr 29 23:46:33 host systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Apr 30 00:48:43 host systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Apr 30 00:48:43 host systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed to run 'start-pre' task: Structure needs cleaning
Apr 30 00:48:43 host systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
```

Comment: I fixed this issue, now the services just won't start! Just reinstalled mariadb  RPM and it worked again

Comment: Just a tip, you mention that you used a "backup copy". Generally you want to use mysqldump to make backups. If a filesystem backup utility backs up one of the databases’ files, and then a few milliseconds later it backs up another one, the state of the database could get corrupted – the database might have been in the middle of an operation during access to the two files. http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/rackspace-cloud-backup-backing-up-databases

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue, now the services just won't start! Just reinstalled mariadb RPM and it worked again. I didn't use YUM cause of dependacies